# Solving a quadratic Inequality

Tags: inequality, graphing-functions, quadratics

My question is:

> Solve  $$9x-14-x^2>0$$

My answer is: $2 < x < 7$

Though I know my answer is right, I want to know in what ways I can solve it and how it can be graphically represented.
Thank you.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect...when x=2 the LHS is 0.

Comment: sorry i typed it wrong

Comment: @Meg Next time try to use LaTeX to type mathematics in this site, or at least leave plenty space: is it 9x or (-9x)  what you wrote? Below you've answers for both cases...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's rearrange the inequality to get:

$x^2 - 9x + 14 < 0$

i.e.

$(x-7)(x-2) < 0$.

Now the product of two numbers is negative if and only if exactly one of the numbers is negative.

So we have that the inequality is satisfied whenever $x-7 < 0$ or $x-2 < 0$ but not both.

This happens when $2 < x < 7$.

Answer (score 1):

$$-9x-14-x^2>0\Longleftrightarrow x^2+9x+14<0$$Since $\,\,\Delta=81-4\cdot 14=25\,$ , the roots of LHS are $\,\,\displaystyle{x_{1,2}=\frac{-9\pm 5}{2}=-7\,,\,-2}\,$, so the inequality is $$(x+7)(x+2)<0\Longrightarrow -7<x<-2$$

Comment: It's $9x$, I think.

Comment: I think it is $\,-9x\,$, but it's a matter of opinion until the OP addresses the issue.

Comment: hey all its 9x...sorry for the confusion

Comment: @Meg Then Gigili's answer's on the money, but you can take any answer's method and do it yourself...and it'd be nice if you pick up some answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

The general way is to use the formula
$$ ax^2 + bx + c = 0 \Rightarrow x_{1,2} = \frac{-b}{2a} \pm \frac{\sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}$$ and see when the function equals zero. Since it is continuous, it is enough to check the sign of $f(x)$ for some $x_1 < x < x_2$. If it is positve, the $f(x) > 0$ for $x_1 < x < x_2$ and $f(x) < 0$ otherwise. Similarly, if it is negative, the $f(x) < 0$ for $x_1 < x < x_2$ and $f(x) > 0$ otherwise.

The key is that a continuous function has the same sign between two zeroes, so the general way is to find all the zeroes (the $x_i$ where $f(x_i)=0$) and then check by substitution what is its sign between each adjacent pair of them ($ x_{i},x_{i+1} $).

Answer (score 1):

Though the question was answered more than 15 months ago, I still found that the part “….. and how it can be graphically represented(?)” was not shown in the form of a graph. The following is the required procedures:-

1. Re-arranging terms, we get $x^2 - 9x + 14 < 0$ (as shown in a previous answer).
2. Solve $x^2 - 9x + 14 = 0$ to get 2 and 7 as the roots.
3. Mark (2, 0) & (7, 0) on the x-axis. They are points that $y = x^2 - 9x + 14$ must go through.
4. The coefficient of $x^2$ is positive indicating the graph of $y = x^2 - 9x + 14$ is an U-shaped parabola that opens its mouth upward.
5. Draw the graph according to the results in (4) & (5). See Fig 1.
6. $y = x^2 - 9x + 14$ and $x^2 - 9x + 14 < 0$ together mean $y < 0$.
7. Look for what xs’ will make (6) to happen. Thus, found all the xs are lying between 2 and 7.
8. Represent the result found (7) graphically and get Fig. 2.
   [image]

Note-1. Open circles are used to indicate the endpoint(s) are not included.

Note-2. All these may seem a bit tedious but it can be completed within a minute or two.