# How to prove that if $-1<x<0$ then $x^2 + x < 0$?

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, quadratics

I am trying to prove an equivalence.

I have already proved that:

$$x^2 + x < 0 \implies -1 < x < 0 $$

using a sub-proof by cases, in which I used the fact that when $xy < 0$, $x$ and $y$ have opposite signs. So I just factored the expression and went from there.

However, I can't seem to find an appropriate way of proving the second implication?

$$-1 < x < 0 \implies  x^2 + x < 0$$

Answer:

I solved it by determining that x + 1 > 0, then since x < 0, (x)( x + 1 ) < 0 ,
then $x^2$ + x < 0

Comment: Let $A=x^2+x=x(x+1)$. Since $-1<x$ by assumption, we have $x+1>0$. Also $x<0$ by assumption. So $A$ equals something positive times something negative...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: $(x+1)>0$, and multiplying an inequality by a positive number doesn't change the inequality arrows.

Comment: Is the second part a hint or a comment?

Comment: It's part of the hint.

Comment: Reference : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/156069/solving-a-quadratic-inequality/542494#542494

Answer (score 1):

To show $-1 < x < 0 \Rightarrow x^2 + x < 0$, observe that, since $0 < \vert x \vert < 1$, 
we have $0< \vert x \vert^2 < \vert x \vert$; to see this, just multiply the inequality $0 < \vert x \vert < 1$ through by $\vert x \vert$.  Next, note that for $x$ in the range $-1 < x < 0$, we have $\vert x \vert^2 = x^2$ and $\vert x \vert = -x$.  Thus $x^2 + x = \vert x \vert^2 - \vert x \vert < 0$ since $\vert x \vert^2 < \vert x \vert$.  ***QED***

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***